# How to use comparator in java to compare diff object values

Tags: java, comparator

```
  public  void dataAnalytics()
  {
  double sum=0;  
  double i=0;
  double minage=20;
  double maxage=20;

    System.out.println("dataAnalytics for the Rural region");

    for (Record ee :RList)
    {
      sum=sum+Double.valueOf(ee.getIncome());
      i++;

      if (ee.getAge()<20)
          minage=ee.getAge();
      if (ee.getAge()>20)
          maxage=ee.getAge();

    }
    System.out.println("Average income for the Rural region is : $"+sum/i);
    System.out.println("Min age  for the Rural region is : "+minage);
    System.out.println("Max age for the Rural region is : "+maxage);

}
```

I have written the following code in java , which goes through an arraylist RList and calculates the sum of all income elements , after which the average is taken. Another function that it does to to calculate the maximum and minum values. How do i accomplish the same operation using the java comparator class?

Comment: the `comparator` is not meant for that, all is does is compare two (custom) objects for equality `public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)` returning 0 if they are equal, 1 if o1 is "greater" than o2 and -1 if o2 is "smaller" than o2.

Comment: @scibuff He's trying to find the maximum and minimum values, a `Comparator` is a perfect tool for the task.

Comment: yes jeff , how do you do that ? cos from all the examples ive seen , the comparator just compares two objects

Comment: you can't do the average but can do the min/max easily

Answer (score 2):

```
class AgeComparator implements Comparator {

    public int compare( Object o1, Object o2 ){

        int age1 = ((Record)o1).getAge();
        int age2 = ((Record)o2).getAge();

        if ( age1 > age2 ){ return 1; }
        else if ( age1 < age2 ){ return -1; }
        return 0;  
    }

}

public void dataAnalytics(){

    Record[] records = rList.toArray();
    Arrays.sort( records, new AgeComparator() );

    int maxAge = (records[0]).getAge();
    int minAge = (records[ records.length - 1]).getAge();

    System.out.println("Min age  for the Rural region is : " + minAge );
    System.out.println("Max age for the Rural region is : " + maxAge );

}
```

Comment: Might as well make 'em generic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class OrderComparator implements Comparator<Order> { 
    @Override
    public int compare(Order b1, Order b2) {
        int i = b1.getCusType().compareTo(b2.getCusType());
        if(i!=0){
        return Integer.compare(b1.getOrderID(), b2.getOrderID());
        }
        else{
        return i;
        }
    }
```

How to compare using comparator by specific word - example 3 types of customers: “NEWBIES”, “REGULARS” and
“VIPs”